# Laravel Count DB Error and Get sum of column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want Count the referals Members for my Affiliate System and want add an Random Value to the Count and get the Sum from it.

Example: (DB Count: 4)  `4 x 0.10= 0.40` (Random Value 0.10$)

Possible?

My other Question,

Heres my Count but dont works correct, i dont know:

```
    @foreach($referalUser as $referData)                                                        
           <?php $count = DB::table('referral_user')->where(['referer_id' => $referData->id])->count(); echo $count; ?>
 @endforeach
```

As results i get always: `0 4 0 0`  but i dont count it in Tables! Not only 4 without zeros.

Anyone can help me?

My DB:

```
referral_user=

id  
referer_id 
referal_id  
created_at  
updated_at
```

Controller:

```
{
      $referalUser = ReferralUser::where('referer_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();

      for($i=0;$i<count($referalUser);$i++)
      {

          $referalUser_name = User::where('id', '=', $referalUser[$i]['referal_id'])->select('username')->get()->toArray();

         $referalUser[$i]['username']=$referalUser_name;




          $referalUser_uniqueid = User::where('id', '=', $referalUser[$i]['referal_id'])->select('uniqueid')->get()->toArray();

         $referalUser[$i]['uniqueid']=$referalUser_uniqueid;



      }
```

Thanks

Comment: are you counting rows?? please enlighten us with your db schema, relationship, columns

Comment: I want Count all Members in my DB where used my Registration URL ID. I have now 4 Members. Or can i do it with "Auth::user()->id" instead of "=> $referData->id])"?

Comment: i have updated my Question.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like:

```
$value = ReferralUser::where('referer_id', $refererId)->count() * $randomValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, i check it out after i get the Count to working with my DB:)

Comment: Typo, use your model `ReferralUser`

Comment: `$value = ReferralUser::where('referer_id', $refererId)->count() * $randomValue;` I had a typo in my answer, here is the fixed version.

Comment: I copied that model name from the code you posted. Are you saying that this doesn't work either? `$referalUser = ReferralUser::where('referer_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();`

Comment: It works for me with only "DB::table" but the Models and Controller are connected, thats why i dont understand the Problem and the Class not found.

Comment: Is your table named correctly as `referral_users`? Or did you rename it something else by any chance? You may need to run `composer dumpautoload` to update the `autoload.php` file.

Comment: Oh sorry dont have understand the Question. yes in my Controller and same Blade works fine. Just the Count not :O inside and outside from "@foreach($referalUser as $referData) " not